# How to search/filter products from a specific collection with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I want to query some products based on a specific collection id or handle.
I cannot use [Combine filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/building-with-the-storefront-api/products-collections/filter-products#step-2-combine-filters), since I have unrelated `tag` values, this is like using an `OR` operator to filter the products, e,g : filters: [{tag: COLOUR_BLUE}, {tag: PATTERN_FLORAL}] this filter will return all the products whose `tag` is `COLOUR_BLUE` **OR** `PATTERN_FLORAL`.
Therefore there is another solution which is the search syntax api, which is `query` inside products field in my graphql.
But this won't query the products for some specific colletion `id` or `handle`.

Code:
Since the search syntax query is only provided for products field in Graphql, how can I query products based on their collections, I am currently having this query:

```
query CollectionProducts(
    $handle: String!
    $country: CountryCode
    $language: LanguageCode
    $productSortKey: ProductCollectionSortKeys
    $productSortReverse: Boolean
    $after: String
  ) @inContext(country: $country, language: $language) {
    collection(handle: $handle) {
      title
      handle
      products(
        first: 10
        after: $after
        reverse: $productSortReverse
        sortKey: $productSortKey
      ) {...}
```

I want to use instead

```
{
  products(query:...)  {...}
}
```

but also query only the products based on their collection `id` or `handle`
How to solve this?